# Error when passing 2 variables in template, django

Tags: python, django

I have the following view

```
@login_required
def myview(request):
    my_strings = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
    var ='12'
    return render(request,
                  'index.html',{'my_strings':my_strings}, {'var': var })
```

But when I try to display `{{ my_strings|random }}` and `{{ var }}` variables in index.html template I get an error message:

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'push'

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass all the values in the same dict.

```
return render(request,
              'index.html', {'my_strings': my_strings, 'var': var })
```

Comment: Oh it was so easy. Thanx a lot Daniel :)